# Removing forward slash from string is causing some issues in PHP, with substr

Tags: php, character

I'm trying to remove a forward-slash from the end of a string.

Seems simple, but I'm having some issues. A really weird charactar is showing up at the end of the string. See my code:

```
function removeSlash($currentURL)
{

    if ( strpos($currentURL , '/') == (strlen($currentURL)-1) )
            $currentURL = substr( $currentURL, 0, -1 );

    return $currentURL;

}

$url = 'http://bob.com/';
var_dump( removeSlash($url) );
```

output:

```
string(15)"http://bob.com"
```

The above `var_dump` says 15 chars were returned, but there is actually 14...

So I ignore it. Then I write a little more code to store it in a DB. The invisible character emerges!

In phpMyAdmin, when i edit the row that the output was inserted in, this is what shows up (in the text field):

> http://bob.com�

No idea how that's happening. I've tried `str_replace()`, `$var[15] = ''` and a load of other methods. All are doing the same!

Comment: I guess it could be the string terminating null byte. Have you tried getting the ascii code of that character? Use `ord()` on each character of the string to find out the ascii value.

Comment: Just a sec. I'll do that now.

Comment: Are you storing it into a binary field rather than a `varchar`? What kind of DB are you using?

Comment: I'm storing it in a varchar field using a MySQL db.

Answer (score 2):

Simple case would be to use

```
rtrim($currentUrl, "/");
```

But based on comments you may have more luck with this.

```
function removeSlash($currentURL)
{

    return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', rtrim($currentURL));
}
```

Comment: I support this answer, though, I don't see any reason to put it in a function by itself. Just use `rtrim($url, '/');` everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, this issue is still occurring.

Comment: Try with the updated answer... this should filter out all of the unprintable characters.

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of character encoding issue going on between PHP and the database. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ah,I tried `rtrim($currentURL);` (without the second param). Your edit seems to have worked (`rtrim($currentURL,"/");`). But why? What was that? Why did it occur? And what does `rtrim()` do to solve it?

Comment: As much as I love a quick, simple fix answer, for this one, I'd prefer an explanation, if that's okay with you :]

Comment: no visible wierd characters. how are you pulling it from the file?

Comment: `file_get_contents()`. I've tried `fopen()`, too. Same result. Also, I've just tried using a different text file and typed a different URL in. Same thing is happening :S

Comment: is the size of the file equal to the number of characters in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$url = trim($url, '/');
```

Your issue is extremely weird though, this may not be the issue.